# While creating android AVD I am getting following error .Target id is not valid. Use 'android list targets' to get the target ids

Tags: android

I am using following command to create avd.

```
./android create avd -n YourAndroid -t 12 -c 100M
```

I have installed all the packages and in the setting I have checked `force htpps://..to be fetched using http://`

But still the error

I am using mac and android-19

Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: I got it working.I had use following command to know my targets ./android list targets and used the same in command to create

Comment: could you post your solution as an answer? That will help anyone else who has the same problem as you did.

Comment: @Tech5 I'm going to close this for two reasons: 1) you've fixed your problem so future answers aren't likely to be validated, and 2) I'm not entirely sure it has to do with SQA. (Maybe it does and I'm just not up on my mobile terms...) If you have objections feel free to respond or hit me up on chat. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android Device manager.